# How to make "Events"/ Scripted Scenes

Tags: java, data-structure, architecture

I want to make cutscenes etc, in my game.

I thought of a similar System like in the RPG Maker:

If you enter a certain Area, a list of commands and arguments is played.

E.g. like this:

[Move Object: Right, right, right; Wait until done;]
[play Sound: sound.sfx]
[Show Message: Speaker: player, message]

I don't want to use external libraries.
Someone has a basic idea on how to implement this?

I thought of a "stack" for these kind of "events", but I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static Script class to handle  to handle scripted sequences and have a state in code that allows the script class to run its sequence without interruption. Here is an idea:

Instances

```
Arraylist<Event> events;

class Event {
  boolean eventComplete;

  //different Initializations based on what the event is.
  //EXAMPLE Timer event
  public Event(float timer);
  //EXAMPLE move event();
  public Event(vector2 target);
}
```

Methods

```
setCountDowntimer(float seconds);
lerpPositiontoTarget(Vector2 target);
MovePositiontoTarget(Vector2 target);
setActive(Object object, boolean active);
```

It's a bit tedious because I'm mobile right now.

Comment: I used Polymorphism to solve this.
I have a base "Event"-Class for example that also has a "Update" method. To move the Character with an Event, I sublass event and pass the character as a parameter. within the update Method I move the player around.

Answer (score 0):

You could develop a bytecode language for this. Take a look at this: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/bytecode.html

Instead of spells as in that example, see the commands as 'walk to' and 'display message' and so on.